# Wrap a function in tf.keras.layers.Lambda

Tags: keras, keras-layer, tf.keras

I have these functions:

```
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tks

def conv_bn_acttivation(x, filters, kernel_size, strides, data_format, activation=relu, is_training=False, name=None):
   conv = tks.Conv2D(....)(x)
   bn = tks.BatchNormalization()(conv, is_training)
   if activation:
      return activation(bn)
   return bn
```

Now, I want to use tf.cond

```
conv =  conv_bn_acttivation(x,....)
short_cut = tf.cond(
        tf.equal(input_channels, filters),
        tks.Lambda(lambda: x), # identity
        tks.Lambda(lambda: conv_bn_activation(x=x, filters=filters, kernel_size=1, strides=1,data_format=data_format))

result = conv + short_cut
```

I got this error in the false_fn 
**TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'** ?!

Comment: I think you have forgotten to call the convolution layer on `x`: `conv = tks.Conv2D(....)(x)`.

Comment: And also the same thing for `Lambda` layers. They must be called on a tensor. And the inner `lambda` function must accept exactly one argument.

Comment: @today thanks. It was a typo. The problem is more complicated.  I need to wrap the tf.cond as tf.keras.layers. I don't need to use Lambda to avoid saving problem after... Any suggestion ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly by "saving problem". You are asking different questions (i.e. error, Lambda layer, saving problem, etc.). Please edit your question and clearly describe what the problem you are trying to solve is.

Comment: @today, By saving problem, I mean you can not use save_model function if you use Lambda Layers in a Keras Model.